# Make property in parent object visible to any of its contained objects

Tags: c#-4.0, scope, parent-child

I have a class `CalculationManager` which is instantiated by a `BackgroundWorker` and as such has a `CancellationRequested` property.

This `CalculationManager` has an `Execute()` method which instantiates some different `Calculation` private classes with their own `Execute()` methods which by their turn might or might not instantiate some `SubCalculation` private classes, in sort of a "work breakdown structure" fashion where each subclass implements a part of a sequential calculation.

What I need to do is to make every of these classes to check, inside the loops of their `Execute()` methods (which are different from one another) if some "global" `CancellationRequested` has been set to true. I put "global" in quotes because this property would be in the scope of the topmost `CalculationManager` class.

So, question is:

> How can I make a property in a class visible to every (possibly nested) of its children?

or put down another way:

> How can I make a class check for a property in the "root object" of its parent hierarchy? (well, not quite, since `CalculationManager` will also have a parent, but you got the general idea.

I would like to use some sort of `AttachedProperty`, but these classes are domain objects inside a class library, having nothing to do with WPF or XAML and such.

Comment: It seems to me that you are asking for Factory Pattern ?

Comment: @MillerKoijam Well, that's possible, but I cannot see right now how I could use factory pattern to get the desired behaviour... (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
public interface IInjectable {
  ICancelStatus Status { get; }
}
public interface ICancelStatus {
  bool CancellationRequested { get; }
}
public class CalculationManager {
  private IInjectable _injectable;
  private SubCalculation _sub;
  public CalculationManager(IInjectable injectable) {
    _injectable = injectable;
    _sub = new SubCalculation(injectable);
  }
  public void Execute() {}
}
public class SubCalculation {
  private IInjectable _injectable;
  public SubCalculation(IInjectable injectable) {
    _injectable = injectable;
  }
}
private class CancelStatus : ICancelStatus {
  public bool CancellationRequested { get; set;}
}

var status = new CancelStatus();
var manager = new CalculationManager(status);
manager.Execute();

// once you set status.CancellationRequested it will be immediatly visible to all
// classes into which you've injected the IInjectable instance
```

Comment: If I understand right, I could create an interface or base class with an "injected parent" passed in the constructor, that would be (possibly automatically) be injected inside any children of that same subclass? Did I get your idea right?

Comment: Yes; this is called dependency injection.